# How to display search with Help.ShowHelp?

Tags: c#, chm

In this code Contents and Index are working but Search doesn't.I am not sure that  HelpNavigator.Find is OK? Is there some other way to display Search from chm file?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Spomenik
{
    public partial class Pomoc : Form
    {
        public Pomoc()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Help_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.Help.ShowHelp(this, "..\\..\\Slika\\SpomenikPomoc.chm");

            //Help.Show(this, "..\\..\\Slika\\SpomenikPomoc.chm"); ne radi jer mi je Help naziv dugmeta
        }

        private void Index_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.Help.ShowHelpIndex(this, "..\\..\\Slika\\SpomenikPomoc.chm");
        }

        private void Search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            **System.Windows.Forms.Help.ShowHelp(this, "..\\..\\Slika\\SpomenikPomoc.chm", HelpNavigator.Find);**
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Specify an empty string (`""`) as the last parameter:

```
Help.ShowHelp(this, "..\\..\\Slika\\SpomenikPomoc.chm", HelpNavigator.Find, "");
```

From [Help.ShowHelp Method (Control, String, HelpNavigator, Object)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7y1a1xy(v=vs.110).aspx):

> If the value specified in the *command* parameter is TableOfContents, Index, or Find, this value should be an **empty string**.

Reflector shows that the `ShowHelp` version with 3 parameters uses `null` as the 4th parameter, rather than `""`. Probably that is why `Find` doesn't work. You need to use the "full" method version with all the needed parameters.